# Laravel not redirecting/ method not returning

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add an access method to a laravel controller that redirects a user if a session is not found. Below is my attempt but it is not working

My route

```
Route::get('textbook/{textbook}/chapter/{chapter}/quiz/{quiz}/takeQuiz', 'QuizesController@takeQuiz')->name('quiz.start');
```

This is my redirect method

```
function access()
{
    if(!session()->has('startQuiz')){
        $parameters = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        return redirect()->route('quiz.start', [$parameters[2], $parameters[4], $parameters[6]]);

    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling that method inside another controller function

```
public function execute(){
        $this->access();
}
```

Comment: have you tried: `return $this->access();`

Comment: Yep! Chrome says "localhost redirected you too many times". Clearing cache doesn't work either

Comment: Tried a different browser? @NooglersBIT

Comment: Tried edge. Doesn't work there either, except the message is different "make sure you have got right web address"

Comment: Do you set the `startQuiz` anywhere? Because you created a loop and that can only happen if `startQuiz` isn't set properly

Comment: You're stuck in a redirect loop. So whatever you're redirecting to, it keeps redirecting forever. Make sure the url you're redirecting them to, doens't match another redirecting url causing the browser to keep redirected.

Comment: Yep, found the error, the route name I was giving is wrong. It is solved now. Thanks!